# How to set the username and password when I use cluster in rocketmq?

Tags: rocketmq

How to set the username and password when I use cluster?
Does rocketmq suppert username and password?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what you've already tried, if anything. Your question would be significantly better if you expanded on your requirements and your experience so far in trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently，rocketMQ not support authentication